# Images imported as planes would only display content in the Display Render Preview

Tags: 3d-view, import

I have imported an image as Plane into my 3d view port, but it only displays the image content in the Display Render Preview.

What do I do so that I can also see the image content in the Display Solid Mode?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling Import Images as Planes Addon gives us two features. We can import image as a plane, or as an Empty.

[image]

Plane won't show you the texture in Solid Shading Mode, while Empty will. The fastest way to add image as empty just drag and drop it into viewport.

[image]

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @OgunlesiTaiwo You're welcome! =)